# How do I split a dataset into training and testing whilst retaining the proportions of binary data (i.e some drugs work some don't)?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataset of drugs, associated chemical features and whether they are "responsive" or "Unresponsive". I need to ensure that once I split the dataset into test and train they both have the same proportion of responsive:unresponsive. I know how to randomly split the data where training is 80% and test is 20%. Not sure how to do the stratified sampling necessary here, is this what I'm meant to use -  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html?

Comment: Divide your set into responsive/unresponsive, take random 80% of each for train data and remainder for test data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `train_test_split` function already has one parameters that allows you keeping the proportion of y. The parameter is `stratify`; and is defined in the documentation as "*If not None, data is split in a stratified fashion, using this as the class labels*".

An example of code would be:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y)
```

Comment: How would I split the data frame into X_train/X_test? will I have to convert it into an array..?

Comment: If you provide X and y to the function, it will return you X_train, X_test, y_train and y_test. X and y can be dataframes or arrays. Please, check some tutorials or tutorials because is quite easy.